# Relative path not executed in windows registry at startup?

Tags: java, windows, jar, registry

I want to run jar file at windows startup. I made an entry at registry successfully.

The jar file is running successfully at system startup.

But the problem is, the file running successfully with absolute path.
The sample path is as follows:

```
C:\Users\...\Desktop\Jars\myJar.jar
```

But I want to run this file with relative path. I developed the application in eclipse, and get the path of "myJar2.jar" and executes within myJar.jar file.

I get the path of "myJar2.jar" file by calling getCanonicalPath() method. In registry , it will display the path as follows:

```
D:\Users\...\ProjectName/Jars/myJar.jar              //path by using getCanonicalPath() method , stored in registry
```

How to run "marJar.jar" at system startup with above relative path.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`D:\Users\...\ProjectName/Jars/myJar.jar`    this is no vaild path, since it contains both `'/'` & `'\'`. eliminate either of those.

to correct  `'\'` or `'/'` in path use this:

```
String path = <some_path_here>;
path = path.replaceAll("\", File.pathSeparator);
path = path.replaceAll("/", File.pathSeparator);
```

Comment: while getting path using getCanonicalPath() method, it will takes '\'.

Comment: If it happens replace with '/' by using replaceAll().